# Firefox on Ubuntu repeatedly asks for password with HTTP authentication

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, passwords, authentication, httpd

I asked this on Stack Overflow and it was suggested that I ask here instead.

I have tried searching for this but nothing I find quite matches my issue. My wife and I run identical setups. We both run current XUbuntu and Firefox. We always apply the latest fixes so we are always at the same level. My setup works fine. On hers it constantly asks for a login and password on sites using HTTP authentication. It remembers her credentials just fine so all she has to do is click OK but as you can probably understand, this can get quite tedious.

I tried wiping her mozilla director and starting fresh only loading her bookmarks. I recently set her up on a new laptop. It's actually my old laptop which was working just fine for me. All I did was copy over her home directory.

As far as I can see, it is something in her specific setup from her own home directory. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: is this issue resolved? can you give us example of some sites when you say `on sites using HTTP authentication.`

Comment: Yeah, without knowing some more details it is hard to say what might be happening. Usually the http auth cache is only cleared when the user (or an add-on) uses the Clear Recent History feature, the server identity changes (such as the http realm) or some add-on manually messes around with things... Also, did you make sure to clear the [right directory](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) and/or did try the [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) feature?

Comment: this should probably be on [ubuntu.se]

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood right, there are these options:

1. Try the Reset Firefox Feature.
2. DELETE the `.mozilla` folder in her home folder and restart firefox

When doing 2. you should decide whether to only delete the `profiles.ini` or the whole directory (which could mean deleting her bookmarks, but not sure).

Your last option is to `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge firefox-*` and reinstall Firefox after that.